# Select All Right Hand Rows for Each Left Hand Row SQL.. HELP!

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am currently looking for a Select statement which will do this..

```
|------Apples------| 
 |--id--|
 - 1   
 - 16
 - 23
 - 42

|------Oranges------| 
 |--id--|
 - a   
 - b
 - c

*SELECT STATEMENT*

|------Fruit Cocktail------| 

|--AppleID--|--OrangeID--|
   1              a
   1              b
   1              c
   16             a
   16             b
   16             c
```

etc...

So basically for every left hand column select that and every right hand column

Thanks 
Daniel

Comment: fyi, this is called a cartesian join

Comment: @Mark Bannister Wanna know something embaressing?

Comment: I didnt know how to accept an answer until about 2 days ago!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple cross join

```
SELECT * FROM Apples, Oranges;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Apples CROSS JOIN Oranges;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Apples
CROSS JOIN
        Oranges
```

or, using implicit join syntax, just that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Apples, Oranges
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

The Boss Answered it for me heres a simulation:

```
Select A.Apple,P.Peach From 
(
Select 1 As Apple
Union
Select 2 As Apple
Union
Select 3 As Apple
Union
Select 4 As Apple
Union
Select 5 As Apple
Union
Select 6 As Apple
) A
Cross Join
(
Select 'a' As Peach
Union
Select 'b'
Union
Select 'c'
Union
Select 'd'
Union
Select 'e'
) P
```

Comment: It is funny your solution does not match the exact question you asked. :)

Comment: Haha i know.. but its close enough! ;)